# PC can't find my HDD after lubuntu 13.10 Crash

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu

I installed zram
aftrer that,
i got out of memory
and after that system crashed
now my PC can't detect my HDD
error i see is, 
`Gave up booting for root device

-boot args

-Check Rootdelay=

-check root=

-missing modules

Alert! /dev/disk/by-uuid/ does not exist

dropping to a shell

(intramfs)_`

I booted from live USB and now I can't find my HDD!

Comment: Was the hard drive full up? You may have damaged your boot sector or it may be a problem with bad sectors. Best thing is to do as TenPlus1 suggests : choose 'try ubuntu' from the flash usb installer and use gparted to inspect the drive, if you can.

Comment: @comrademike I can't open the HDD, the icon is always in busy position when opening HDD

Comment: Type:  mount -l   in terminal and list what appears...

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to this would be to boot from your live CD or Flash Drive and check to see if the hard-drive in question can be accessed from there, if so then thankfully your partitions are ok and you could perform a new install of Lubuntu to fix everything once more without adding zram, leave that for Lubuntu 14.04 in April...

Comment: I can't open the HDD, the icon is always in busy position when opening HDD